# phone number lookup program

Tags: python

I am having a problem with my array homework, I need to enter a name then the program has to return the number, but all I can get it to do is return all of them

```
def main():
    people = ['todd','david','angela','steve','bob','josh','ben']
    phoneNumbers = ['234-7654','567-1234','888-8745','789-5489','009-7566','444-6990','911-9111']

    found = False
    index = 0

    searchValue = raw_input('Enter a name to search for phone number: ')

    while found == False and index < len(people):
        if people[index] == searchValue:
            found = True
        else:
            index = index + 1

    if found:
        print 'the phone number is: ',phoneNumbers
    else:
        print 'that name was not found'

main()
```

Comment: do you have to use arrays? dictionaries are a better datatype here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `index` to print the phone number you want, rather than all of them:

```
if found:
    print 'the phone number is: ', phoneNumbers[index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have explicitly given you the answer, but based on the way the question has been written, I'm concerned about comprehension. So I'll go into a little more detail. Right now, the way your code is written, you are telling the program to print all of them. (Code is stupid, and only does exactly what you tell it!)

so the line

```
print 'the phone number is: ',phoneNumbers
```

will always print all of the phone numbers.

Now for funsies, try something like:

```
print 'the phone number is: ',phoneNumbers[0]
```

And you will notice that the first (or zero indexed) item in your list of phone numbers will print. (You can put any numbers from 0-6 in there and get all the phone numbers one by one).

Now for your homework, you are concerned with printing the phone number that matches the name, not just the first one. We assume that there is a one-to-one mapping of your names to phone numbers. So the zeroeth phoneNumber matches to 'todd', the one'th phoneNumber matches to 'david' and so on. If you find a name in your list, say you are looking for 'angela', then the line of code that says:

```
    if people[index] == searchValue:
```

when you get to 'angela', then index at that time will be equal to '2'. (maybe temporaraly put a 'print index' just after that line to convince yourself of this).

So now, if you print phoneNumbers[2] or, phoneNumbers[index], it will print the number that matches 'angela'.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
print 'the phone number is: ',phoneNumbers
```

You should use

```
print 'the phone number is: ',phoneNumbers[index]
```

another best option is do it with dict something like:

```
contacts = {'todd':'123-456', 'mauro': '678-910'}
searchValue = raw_input('Enter a name to search for phone number: ')

if contacts.has_key(searchValue):
     print 'The %s phone number is %s' %(searchValue, contacts[searchValue])
else:
     print 'that name was not found'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this instead:

```
...

searchValue = raw_input( ....

people_numbers = dict(zip(people,phoneNumbers))
if searchValue in people_numbers:
  print 'the phone number is :', people_numbers[searchValue]
else:
  print '.....
```